# Formatar data e hora e listar de acordo com a data atual

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, expressões-lambda

Essa aplicação tem duas tabelas: Alunos e Ocorrencias. Para mostrar as ocorrências eu consigo tranquilamente... Só que agora me surgiu uma nova regra de negócio: Mostrar as ocorrências por data. Então basicamente seria o seguinte, eu teria que mostrar as ocorrências mais atuais de acordo com a data, ou seja, se por exemplo gerei uma ocorrência ontem, então vai mostra-la em evidência acima das outras, mas se eu gerar uma hoje, essa de hoje terá que ficar em evidência. Como por exemplo, o que acontece aqui no SOpt. Como é que eu poderia usar a formatação nativa do c# para mostrar a data e a hora/minutos. Ou seja, eu queria poder mostrar além da data, a hora e os minutos, pois preciso desses dados pra que na hora de listar.

E como que eu conseguiria fazer essa listagem colocando as atuais a vista do usuário, ou seja, em evidência ?

Aqui vou mostrar como que está a busca que faço no banco pra mostrar as ocorrências:

**A ActionResult que varre a tabela e mostra os dados(Que por enquanto, mostro os nomes, mas quero mostrar os nomes e as datas, assim como foi descrito acima):**

```
public ActionResult Inicio()
{
    List<Ocorrencia> resultado = db.Ocorrencias.Include(o => o.Aluno).ToList();
    return View(resultado);
}
```

Então basicamente eu busco apenas os nomes, e com isso as novas ocorrências vão ficando em baixo das antigas, e não é isso que preciso. Eu preciso que as novas, listadas por data, fique acima, em evidência.... Mas como que faço isso ?

Comment: O que queres fazer é: ordenar as ocorrências por data, e na view apresentar a data no formato `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm` certo?

Comment: Exatamente isso ! É porque da maneira que está, lista todas, e a ordem é: as novas ficam embaixo das antigas...

Comment: @ÉrikThiago você já percebeu que todas as suas postagens precisam ser editadas por outros usuários? Dê uma olhada como está ficando depois da edição que as pessoas fazem para ver como usar o editor corretamente. O que você fica confuso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se bem entendi, queres listar todas as tuas ocorrências ordenadas por data.
Se assim for, basta na query feita no controller, ordenar por data:

```
public ActionResult Inicio()
{
    List<Ocorrencia> resultado = db.Ocorrencias.Include(o => o.Aluno).OrderBy(c => c.DataAOrdenar).ToList();
    return View(resultado);
}
```

Para apresentares a data no formato `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm`, na view fazes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataAOrdenar, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")
```

Comment: Nossa, BOA demais e muito simples ! E eu achando que ter que mudar tudo ! Só uma dúvida, como ainda não coloquei a data no model, eu poderia colocar um _DateTime_ pra data sem precisar usar as _annotations_ nativas do c# ?

Comment: Sim, estou a assumir que tens um DateTime no model. Se o teu campo for DateTime não precisas de fazer nada para além do que coloquei aqui

Comment: Cara que ótimo, é porque tem as _annotations_ do c#, tipo _Required_, _Display_, _StringFormat_. Como ainda não tenho esse atributo no model, e como vou criar ele vai ser um _DateTime_, dessa forma não preciso formatar ele no model e sim na View... Certo ?

Comment: Certo. Basta definires como `public DateTime DataAOrdenar { get; set; }`. O formato é sempre manipulável na view ou no controller, por isso não precisas fazer nenhuma string format

Comment: Cara, muuito obrigado ! Serio mesmo ! Quando chegar em casa eu vejo certinho. E se der erro posto aqui !

Comment: Deu certo ! Muuuito obrigado !